# Has anyone had a look at DIME, the new Darkmail infrastructure, yet?

Tags: email, protocols

*Background*. In 2013, Lavabit and Silent Circle formed the [Dark Mail Technical Alliance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Mail_Alliance) and launched the [Darkmail](https://darkmail.info/) project to create the *Dark Internet Mail Environment* (DIME) – a new mail architecture aiming to provide secure, end-to-end encrypted mailing.

In 2015, specification drafts for [DIME [large document]](https://darkmail.info/spec), something named [STACIE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ladar-stacie-00) and a protocol named [DMAP](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-melnikov-dmap-00) have been released. Another protocol named DMTP is specified within the DIME specification draft. (I assume DMAP and DMTP are to replace IMAP and SMTP.)

In January 2017, Lavabit – which had shutdown in 2013 – [relaunched](https://lavabit.com/) and with it Ladar Levison released the source of its server [Magma](https://github.com/lavabit/magma) and the [DIME library](https://github.com/lavabit/libdime), see also the [introduction on Lavabit](https://lavabit.com/explain-lavabit.html).

This was two months ago. Now, the question:

> Has anyone reviewed the specifications? What is their verdict?

(And moreover on a rather trivial note, why hasn’t this created more fuss? I’ve seen some articles mentioning it, but there seems to be little interest in DIME itself – why is that?)